# add "onload click on <a> function" to a link send by email

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to add to the link sent by email a code or something to make the landing page click on a  link.

Let me explain:
I have a product page that includes a review button (the  link), and the emails sent by the hosting only includes a link to the product page.  So, when the user click on it, they go to the product page, then the user have to go down to the "add a review" button and click on it to be able to write the review.  So, my idea is to find a way to add an extra coding to the emailed link, that make the product page "click" on the  link on this page to load the review form when the page loads.

I have been trying to modify the code to make it more friendly for users, but the ASP coding of the hosting (no accessible from my side) is not allowing me to do many things...

Comment: this is the form inside the page:  

<aside id="createreview-modal" class="createreview createreview-modal modal text-left" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">

when the <a> link is clicked, it changes to this:

<aside id="createreview-modal" class="createreview createreview-modal modal text-left in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific client side behaviour when coming from the mail, you have to have a different url. If you won't make a separate page, you can add a fragment like #review and either have a direct anchor on the page so client is just scrolled there or you can check the fragment on load and make a click/scroll/navigation however you need using javascript.